# Trying to figure out variable scope in VBA Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have made a Userform with a SpinButton and a Label. When the user hits the Spinup it would increment a variable then display that index from an array to the label. Or the other way with the SpinDown. The problem I keep running into is when I try to use a variable from a module to increment or decrement to adjust the index of the array. I've tried it this way:

```
Private Sub SpinButtonM_SpinDown()
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim a As Integer

    a = 1
    Counter = Counter - a

    UserForm2.Month.Caption = Counter
End Sub
```

And I have tried it this way both of which seems to give me errors:

```
Private Sub SpinButtonM_SpinDown()
    Dim monthArray

    monthArray = Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep",...)

    Module1.Counter = Module1.Counter + 1
    UserForm2.Month.Caption = Module.Counter
End Sub
```

Comment: Are Module1-Counter and Module-Counter the same variables? Are you using  [Option Explicit](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html) at the very beginning of your code?

Comment: Yes they are the same, no ill have to try the option explicit.

Comment: @pnuts Whomever decides the tagging rules needs to reconsider. The current guidelines are ridiculous. It says, "*Combine the Excel tag with r, VSTO, C#, VB.NET, PowerShell, OLE automation, and other programming related tags and questions.*" So it's OK to add those completely external things to and `Excel` tag, but it is NOT ok to combine `VBA` with an Excel tag? This has the effect of classifying completely Excel related questions that have a VBA component as not even part of Excel. These questions are not listed in a search of `Excel`. VBA is an integral part of Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `Counter` to work within the userform while declaring it in Module1, you will need to declare it as Public in Module1. This sets it's scope to the whole project.

I don't see a reason to place any of the variables outside of the userform for what you are doing, but to make your revolving month spinner work AND to use variables from Module1, then this is what I'd do:

In Module1, place this code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Counter As Long
Public monthArray As Variant
```

And in the userform, place this code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SpinButtonM_SpinUp()
    UpdateMonth 1
End Sub
Private Sub SpinButtonM_SpinDown()
    UpdateMonth -1
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateMonth(Delta As Long)
    Counter = Counter + Delta
    If Counter < 1 Then Counter = 12
    If Counter > 12 Then Counter = 1
    Month = monthArray(Counter)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    monthArray = [transpose(text(date(,row(1:12),1),"mmm"))]
    UpdateMonth 1
End Sub
```

Note: this assumes that `Month` is the name of the label.

Note: rather than using global variables from Module1, it would make more sense in your scenario to limit their scope to the userform and to declare them as Private. You would do that by placing them directly under the Option Explicit in the userform code module, and by replacing `Public` with `Private` for each variable. Then you would not need Module1... at least for what is described in the question.

Note: as a side effect of placing any of your variables in Module1 as Public (this is what makes them available in the userform) closing the userform does NOT end the program. When you re-open the form the Month will not be on `Jan`. Instead, it will be where it was when the userform was closed, plus one. To override that behavior, you will need to add a `UserForm_Terminate()` procedure to the userform and place an `End` statement in it. This will force the program to end when the userform is closed. HOWEVER, following the advice to re-scope the variables to the userform eliminates this side effect completely, which means you would not need the `UserForm_Terminate()` procedure at all.

**UPDATE**

In response to your comment, to alter this solution so that the current month displayed by the spinner is retained between program runs, even when the workbook is closed and then reopened, you need to save the current month each time the spinner changes. A clean way to do this is to store the `Counter` value as a Named Constant. Like any Defined Name this named constant will be available to be inspected via the Name Manager (Control-F3) from the worksheet.

Note that the name of our stored named constant is `_CounterMemory`:

```
Private Sub SpinButtonM_SpinDown()
    UpdateMonth -1
End Sub
Private Sub SpinButtonM_SpinUp()
    UpdateMonth 1
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateMonth(Delta As Long)
    Counter = Counter + Delta
    If Counter < 1 Then Counter = 12
    If Counter > 12 Then Counter = 1
    Month = monthArray(Counter)
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "_CounterMemory", Counter
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim n&
    monthArray = [transpose(text(date(,row(1:12),1),"mmm"))]
    On Error Resume Next
    n = [_CounterMemory]
    If n = 0 Then n = 1
    Counter = n
    UpdateMonth 0
End Sub
```

One of many advantages of this route as opposed to storing the value in a cell in a worksheet is discretion. It is out of the way. It is not susceptible to normal user tampering because the vast majority of normal users do not know of the Name Manager. If a worksheet gets deleted, there is no impact on this solution. This is a clean way to facilitate variable persistence.

As a point of clarification note that a Named Constant is not the same thing as a constant declared in a VBA module with the CONST statement. Rather a Named Constant is similar to a Named Range on a worksheet, but instead of naming a range we are naming a literal value (in other words, a constant value). But we can create and read that value from VBA code and that is precisely what my update does.

Comment: Hi ExcelHero could you please explain the code `[transpose(text(date(,row(1:12),1),"mmm"))]`   I'm flummoxed by this.

Comment: @HarveyFrench Hello Harvey. It's just a simple array formula. To test it, copy the formula (but not the square brackets surrounding it) and go to any worksheet. Select any vertical range of 12 cells, and in the Formula Bar at the top of Excel enter an equal sign and then paste the formula. Confirm with Control-Shift-Enter. You'll see the 12 months listed as formatted by the TEXT() function in the formula. This is the format that the OP wants.

Comment: Thank you for the information. The program will be used many times during the same month so having it be able to stay on the same month would work just fine.

Comment: @HarveyFrench So back to the VBA... The square brackets are just a shorthand version of the Evaluate() method with the caveat that only literal text can be evaluated this way... so no variables allowed between the square brackets. We don't need any here. Evaluate() always does its business as Array Formula evaluation and so we get an array back if the formula would produce and array on the worksheet.

Comment: @DakotaMiller You are welcome, but be aware that closing the workbook will definitely END the program and so the next time the workbook is opened and the userform shown, it WILL default to `Jan`.

Comment: Could I just place a value in a hidden worksheet and when the workbook opens again get that value and start from there?

Comment: @DakotaMiller Yes. In fact there is a better way. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sweet Thanks so much!

Comment: @HarveyFrench Sorry, I meant to paste it into the worksheet in a range of 12 HORIZONTAL cells, not VERTICAL cells, and then array-enter it.

Comment: @DakotaMiller OK. At the bottom of my answer I have added an update top the code to handle the variable persistence.

Comment: Thank you again, and from the way it looks you don't need to declare a variable as a Constant?

Comment: @ExcelHero Thanks.  I'd forgotten about [] being equivalent to Eval.... It makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

If they are declared inside a sub or function the are only usable in that sub or function. Once you leave that function it is gone.

If you declare them at the module or form level, you can access then throughout that module or form.

```
Option explicit
Private strA as string

Sub test()
    Dim strB As String

    strA = "A"
    strB = "B"

    Test2
End Sub

Sub Test2()
    msgbox strA

    'msgbox strB This will not work as it is only available for sub test
End Sub
```

So you probably want to move

```
Dim Counter As Integer
```

To the very top of your code.

See some info here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141693